# YouTube iframe API error on line 49

Tags: youtube-api

Everything works great in chrome and ff. i have the code, and some function to stop the video on slide change (i have 4 videos on the page)
i have tried div with id and calling

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var video1;

    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        video1 = new YT.Player('video1', {
            width: videoWidth,
            height: videoHeight,
            videoId: '**VIDEOID**'
        });
    }
```

and i have tried having the Iframe in the source and than calling only

```
video1 = new YT.Player('video1');
```

within the onyoutubeplaterapiready

the error i get only on IE (i tested it on 8) is: 
Message: Unspecified error.
Line: 49
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://www.youtube.com/embed/**VIDEOID**?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://o

what can be done with that?

Comment: I've fot this error when I was removing the video via javascript as soon as the video was ended. Also you should check if you were on https://

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm late with this but I had the same error, I was loading the YouTube player inside a modal and when I closed the modal I got the error on IE8. The thing was that I had registered "onStateChange" event in the API and when the modal was closed, and the player removed from the DOM, I got that error because that event was trying to communicate with an element that doesn't exist any more.